# Python dictionary simple way to add a new key value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Say you have,

```
foo = 'bar'
d = {'a-key':'a-value'}
```

And you want

```
d = {'a-key':'a-value','foo':'bar'}
e = {'foo':foo}
```

I know you can do,

```
d['foo'] = foo

#Either of the following for e
e = {'foo':foo}
e = dict(foo=foo)
```

But, in all these way to add the variable foo to dict, I have had to use the word `foo` twice; once to indicate the key and once for its value.

It seems wasteful to me to use `foo` twice. Is there a simpler way, in which you can tell python **"Add this variable to the dictionary with its name as the key and its value as the value"**?

Comment: how do you arrive at your `foo = 'bar'`. Is there a way to skip this state? or to have `dict`: `{'foo': 'bar'}` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actutally using `foo` twice is remarkably common in python programs.  It is used extensively for passing on arguments eg

```
def f(foo, bar):
    g(foo=foo)
```

Which is a specialised case of the dictionary manipulations in your question.

I don't think there is a way of avoiding it without resorting to [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(programming)#Referential_opacity), so I think you'll have to live with it.

Comment: Yes. It is definitely common, and I think about avoiding it, each time. My question, in general covers this general repetition too.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this

```
def add_dry_foo(d, namespace, fooName):
    d[fooName] = namespace[fooName]

foo = 'oh-foo'
d = {}
add_dry_foo(d, locals(), 'foo')
print d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
name = 'foo'
d[name] = vars[name]
```

I don't see the difference between your `d` and `e` cases: both set 'foo' to the value of foo.

It gets trickier if you want to bury this in a function:

```
def add_variable(d, name):
    # blah
```

because then it has to use `inspect` to start poking around in frames.

This sounds like a larger problem that might have a nicer solution if you wanted to describe it to us.  For example, if the problem is that you don't care just about foo, but in fact, a whole slew of local variables, then maybe you want something like:

```
d.update(locals())
```

which will copy the names and value of all the local variables into `d`.

Comment: Ned: This is a common django pattern, return render_to_resp('template', {'a':a, 'b":b, 'c':c}). Wont it be better if I could do, render_to_resp('template', func(a, b, c, d))

Comment: Exactly: What about: `render_to_response('template', locals())`?

Comment: Works, but to allow a possibly unsafe template access to *all* your local variables may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

To add all the local variables to a dict you can do:

```
d.update(locals())
```

The same works for function calls:

```
func(**locals())
```

Note that depending on where you are `locals()` might of course contain stuff that should not end up in the dict. So you could implement a filter function:

```
def filtered_update(d, namespace):
    for key, value in namespace.items():
        if not key.startswith('__'):
            d[key] = value

filtered_update(d, locals())
```

Of course the Python philosophy is "explicit is better than implicit", so generally I would walk the extra mile and do this kind of stuff by hand (otherwise you have to be careful about what goes on in your local namespace).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass all of `locals()` (which may be a security risk if you don't fully trust the function you're sending the data too), a one-line answer could be this:

`dict([ (var, locals()[var]) for var in ['foo', 'bar'] ])`

or in Python 3.0 this would become possible:

`{ var: locals()[var] for var in ['foo', 'bar'] }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval, although I'm not sure that I'd recommend it.

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> foo = 'wibble'
>>> def add(d, name):
        d[name] = eval(name)


>>> add(d, 'foo')
>>> d
{'foo': 'wibble'}
```

**Edit:**
I should point out why I don't recommend "eval". What happens if you do something like this? (from: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-November/042854.html)

```
>>> s = "(lambda loop: loop(loop)) (lambda self: self(self))"
>>> add(d, s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    add(d, s)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 2, in add
    d[name] = eval(name)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  ...
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you are talking about is an 
enhancement to parameter passing functionality:

```
def func(*vars):
```

provides a tuple of ordered values without keys

```
def func(**vars):
```

provides a dict of key value pairs, that 
  MUST be passed as **key=value** pairs.

```
def func(***vars):
```

WOULD PROVIDE a dict of key value pairs, 
  passed either explicitly as **key=value**, 
  or implicitly as **key** (a variable,
  literals would cause error without **key=**)

SO:

```
(x1,x2,x3) = (1,2,3)
def myfunc(***vars):
  retrun vars
myfunc(x1,x2,x3)
>>> {'x1':1,'x2':2,'x3':3}
```

But of course, this is just wishful thinking...